# Send Complex data to Restful Web Service -- API design

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-url, restful-architecture

I am trying to convert some of the SOAP based web services to Restful web services. In one of our existing SOAP based web service, we pass in a RequstDTO and the web service returns a ResponseDTO. The RequestDTO and ResponseDTO are both complex Java classes, which contain other custom JavaBean classes inside. It is a "READ" operation, so it naturally maps to the `"GET"` REST operation. Converting the ResponseDTO into XML or JSON has no issue. But I am not sure how to convert the RequestDTO into RESTful API.

1. The URL is going to be quite long, if I convert all the data in the RequestDTO into the query string. RESTful web service is usually consumed by application, thus the browser URL length limitation does not really apply. But a short URL is still preferred in most cases.
2. Some attributes in the RequestDTO might have PHI sensitive information and I prefer not to put them in the URL.

One solution is to embed the request data in the request body, even though it is a GET operation. But based on my research, such way is discouraged
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/message/9962

So what is the alternative? What is the right way to design this?

Comment: Can you give some examples. Otherwse itll be difficult to answer

Comment: Is this a GET operation, or a query of some kind?

Comment: It is a query. I am trying to decide if I should use GET with query string and GET with request body or POST operation.

Comment: I am having a similar scenario and found this thread. Can you please post the resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly sure why you would need to pass the requestDTO to make the REST call.

Normally you just do something like this

GET   /Resource/id
Now if the resource you want is like a secondary resource.. Example, you have a User and credit cards belonging to a user.

GET  /User/{user_id}

GET  /User/{user_id}/CreditCards/{credit_card_id}

And of course this can be nested however many times you want.

Comment: In our case, the query is much more complex than basing on user_id and credit_card_id. I need to send a complex object containing about 20-30 fields to the web service to retrieve the data I need. Also, as I mentioned in the question, some data are PHI related and I preferred not to put them in the url.

Comment: @smk: not everything in the world is a resource, with an address.